# jquery mobile link from php to html not working but URL does change

Tags: php, html, jquery-mobile

Ok so when I login to my app (index.html) I get taken to login.php, from here I want a menu for the user but none of my links are working. I have tried numerous things but cannot figure it out. Also when I click on a link the URL will change to the page I want to see (jobs.html) but on screen it only shows my index.html page.

My go back link on login.php works but none of the others
What can I do ?
index.html

```
    <form id="login" name="login" action="login.php" method="POST" data-ajax="false" >

        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" required="required"/><br />
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" required="required"/><br />
        <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" id="loginSubmit" value="Login" />
     </form>
```

login.php

```
<div data-role="content">
<p>Welcome to <strong><?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>
 </strong>.</p>
<input type="button" data-ajax="false" href="jobs.php" value="jobsss" />
<a   href="webport.html" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go Back</a>
<a  data-role="button" href="jobs.html" data-ajax="false" class="">Jobs Zone</a>
<a  data-role="button" href="other.html" class=""> Zone</a>
```

This has really stumped me. Thanks for any help

Comment: You may need to add `rel="external"` to your `href`'s

Comment: That does not work, again the URL will change but it will not show content on jobs.html

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have any PHP inside your `.html` files, would you?

Comment: No the only php I have is in the php file.

Comment: Well then, this has no bearing on PHP.

Comment: In your `login.php` file, PHP has done its job. If other pages are not showing up, it's not PHP's fault, it's the HTML structure and how it's been put together. This has nothing to do with PHP, therefore your question should not be tagged as `php`

Comment: are you loading jQ and jQM js/css in other pages?

Comment: Yes Omar in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use ajax for your problem.

```
formData = {
    username: $("#username"),
    password: $("#password")
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "login.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.replace("jobs.html");
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

your login.php need to send JSON format in able request and response. You can refer to this site.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/